# How to edit my code to stop uploading of allowed file when at least 1 of them is not valid?

Tags: php

I have the following code that I use to upload two files from two inputs. (no multiple).

The problem is that if 1 file is correct and the other is not, for example one is .jpg and the other is .exe, the .jpg is uploaded and the .exe is not.

How can I edit my code so that if at least 1 of the 2 files are not correct, nothing will be uploaded and display the appropriate message?

If both files are OK, then proceed with the upload.

messages: 1. too big file 2. no valid extension

```
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "gif", "zip", "bmp", "pdf", "doc", "docx");
$max_file_size = 1024*300; //100 kb
$path = "uploads/"; // Upload directory
$count = 0;


    // Loop $_FILES to execute all files
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) { 



            if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                header("Location: http://www.");

            }
            elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                header("Location: http://www.");

            }
            else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
            $random = rand(1,30);
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$random.$name)) {
                    $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded files
                    header("Location: http://www.");
                }
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to do it in a separate loop:

```
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "gif", "zip", "bmp", "pdf", "doc", "docx");
$max_file_size = 1024*300; //100 kb
$path = "uploads/"; // Upload directory
$count = 0;

foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name)
{
    if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size)
    {
        header("Location: http://www.");
        exit();
    }
    elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) )
    {
        header("Location: http://www.");
        exit();
    }
}

// Loop $_FILES to execute all files
foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name)
{
    $random = rand(1,30);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$random.$name))
    {
        $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded files
        header("Location: http://www.");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Will yo suggest me any additional security features please?

Answer (score 0):

`move_uploaded_file` should be out of the for each. Loop though once to make sure everything is valid, and a second time to actually move the upload.

The second loop should not be run if there are any errors from the original loop